# Deploy OVA to VCenter with Terraform

Tags: vsphere, terraform

I am by no means a knowledgeable VMWare user at this point. I think this might just be a case where I just don't understand some essential concepts.

I'm trying to deploy a VM into a VCenter, I have an OVA (template?) that I want to deploy with.

Currently I have unpacked the OVA, uploaded the VMDKs I found therein to a datastore, and then used this terraform definition:

```
provider "vsphere" {
  user = "${var.vsphere_user}"
  password = "${var.vsphere_password}"
  vsphere_server = "${var.vsphere_server}"
  allow_unverified_ssl = true
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "primary" {
  name =  "myvm"
  vcpu = 2
  memory = 16384
  datacenter = "${var.vsphere_datacenter}"
  resource_pool = "/DATA_CENTER/host/10.132.260.000"

  network_interface = {
    label = "Private Network - vmnic0 vmnic2"
    ipv4_address = "10.132.260.001"
    ipv4_gateway = "10.132.260.002"
    ipv4_prefix_length = 26
  }

  disk {
    datastore = "datastore1"
    vmdk = "/path/to/vmdk/"
    bootable = true
    type = "thin"
  }
}
```

Which gets stuck, because it can't open the VMDK.

When I deploy the OVA with ovftool the `vmdk` that the vm is deployed with is very different.

> An error was received from the ESX host while powering on VM myvm.
>   Failed to start the virtual machine. Module DiskEarly power on failed.
>   Cannot open the disk
>   '/vmfs/volumes/557fc17b-c078f45c-f5bf-002590faf644/template_folder/my_vm.vmdk'
>   or one of the snapshot disks it depends on.  The file specified is not
>   a virtual disk

Should I be uploading the `OVA` file to the datastore instead and change my disk block to look like:

```
disk {
  datastore = "datastore1"
  template = "/path/to/ova/"
  type = "thin"
}
```

Or am I just out of luck here? Also, the terraform provider for vsphere doesn't correctly receive the error from VCenter and just continues to poll even though the vm failed.

Comment: If anyone knows where the code for this resource is; I would also like to know and possibly contribute back.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: @Rekovni I haven't had a chance to try. I had been trying to follow development issues concerning this. I really don't know how I would even go about building this though.

Comment: Hmm, there is a ticket at the moment for OVA upload support (https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-vsphere/issues/74), but doesn't mention anything about using a template to OVA.

Comment: I'm just trying to do something similar but with a vmdk file, but having issues with that, but OVA would be a lot easier!

Comment: Try first to import OVA file into vCenter, this way you will create a new virtual machine. Then resize machine disk size to whatever suits your needs. Finallly convert it into a Virtual Machine template. This is the template you must use on `template` property on terraform-vsphere-provider.

Answer (score 0):

OVA contains `streamOptimized` disks. If you directly upload to the datastore vSphere doesn't recognize it as a VMDK for a VM.

You can use `vmware-vdiskmanager` tool to convert the streamOptimized disk to sparse disk.

`vmware-vdiskmanager -r ova_extracted.vmdk  -t 0 destination.vmdk`